# Python - Threading - Console o/p disapper

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I am trying hands on with Socket Programming.Below is my server side code and I have not listed client side code here which is similar. As soon as the thread(in the try block) is called my console o/p disappears. Not sure how to handle this.Running it on DOS of Windows 7.Although I tried to read some existing discussion but found it was not very useful. Any help appreciated. Thanks..Ravi.
Code block:

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import thread

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 15000)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)
connection, client_address = sock.accept()
Servername = raw_input('Starting the chat(enter "QUIT" to discontinue), Please enter your name: ')

def Server_outgoing():
    while True:
        outgoing_message_server = raw_input()
        if (outgoing_message_server == 'Quit' or outgoing_message_server == 'quit' or outgoing_message_server == 'QUIT'):
            print "Server has decided to abort the chat - Bye bye"
            break
        print "######################################################################"
        print >>sys.stderr, '"%s" : Printing outgoing message from Server "%s"' % (Servername, outgoing_message_server)
        print "######################################################################"
        connection.sendall(outgoing_message_server)     
try:
    thread.start_new_thread(Server_outgoing, ())
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: It looks like you don't really understand sockets, threading *or* blocking. I put together what *might* help explain things [here](https://draftin.com/documents/896689?token=ZT_Lt2VVDbG0UjxQpp4IJN85JrvNEBSh1ulFIcyuRl9EbbsCwRDRmqWsGNP-G3awHfbxc6tnU5oppofHGWeEA5U). I don't really have a threading example on there, though, because it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys..This worked..:

```
    thread1 = Thread(target=Server_outgoing, args=())
    thread1.start()
    thread1.join()
```